# How to put div stack to bottom of the page once clicked with animation without affecting style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanted to put the `clicked div` to bottom of the stack without loosing any `styles`  with some `animation`

**Question**: when i `clicked` a `div` it should go to **bottom** without loosing any styles

**here is codepen:**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjByzo

```js
$(function(){
  $('.box').on('click',function(){
      var cloned = $(this).clone();
      $(this).remove();
      $('#wrapper').append(cloned);
   });
});
```

```css
div.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background:red;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.box:active{
  background:yellow;
}
div.box2{
  background:green;
}
div.box3{
  background:orange;
}

div.box{
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <!-- for box 2 -->
    <div class="box box2">7</div>
    <div class="box box2">8</div>
    <div class="box box2">9</div>
    <div class="box box2">10</div>
    <div class="box box2">11</div>
    <div class="box box2">12</div>
    <!-- for box 3-->
    <div class="box box3">13</div>
    <div class="box box3">14</div>
    <div class="box box3">15</div>
    <div class="box box3">16</div>
    <div class="box box3">17</div>
    <div class="box box3">18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I seems to be working for me, please explains what goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try use `$(this).insertAfter($("#wrapper .box:last"))`; I believe it solves the problem that you can only click them once.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($("#wrapper .box:last"))
  });
});
```

```css
div.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.box:active {
  background: yellow;
}

div.box2 {
  background: green;
}

div.box3 {
  background: orange;
}

div.box {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <!-- for box 2 -->
  <div class="box box2">7</div>
  <div class="box box2">8</div>
  <div class="box box2">9</div>
  <div class="box box2">10</div>
  <div class="box box2">11</div>
  <div class="box box2">12</div>
  <!-- for box 3-->
  <div class="box box3">13</div>
  <div class="box box3">14</div>
  <div class="box box3">15</div>
  <div class="box box3">16</div>
  <div class="box box3">17</div>
  <div class="box box3">18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i add animation something like `bounced` from `top` to `bottom` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just append "this" in the click event function. Also, by floating the DIVs, they won't have the extra space added and the style remain the same after click.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.box').on('click',function(){
      $('#wrapper').append(this);
   });
});
```

```css
div.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background:red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:26px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
div.box:active{
  background:yellow;
}
div.box2{
  background:green;
}
div.box3{
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <!-- for box 2 -->
    <div class="box box2">7</div>
    <div class="box box2">8</div>
    <div class="box box2">9</div>
    <div class="box box2">10</div>
    <div class="box box2">11</div>
    <div class="box box2">12</div>
    <!-- for box 3-->
    <div class="box box3">13</div>
    <div class="box box3">14</div>
    <div class="box box3">15</div>
    <div class="box box3">16</div>
    <div class="box box3">17</div>
    <div class="box box3">18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution man , if have time can you add some bouncing animation from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position:fixed;` property in your `clicked div`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would position fixed help?

Comment: If he is wanting to fix the position of the div at the bottom of the stack regardless of user behaviors, 'position: fixed' is one way to accomplish this using straight CSS.  This way it always stays in the same place, in this case - the bottom.  Did I misinterpret the question?? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I believe he wants to move the element he click, to the end of the wrapper.

Comment: I see - i thought his ask was to fix the postilion to the bottom only. Looking at @Jeff's answer above I see what he was asking.  Good solution he gave.